# Python requests header. How to parse this? invalid syntax with ast?

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, http-headers, tls1.2

I want to convert a header string to a dictionary. The string are form various sources so the format is a bit complex.

This is an example:

```
import ast
import re

header="{'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Content-Security-Policy': "default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' https://www.google.com/ https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/; form-action 'self' https://agilemail.createsend.com/ https://www.createsend.com/t/subscribeerror https://www.createsend.com/t/securedsubscribe; frame-src https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/; connect-src 'self'", 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Amz-Cf-Id': 'XZOj8R9YBVEMbHv93beUYFIizxUbrGKL_LVrS1gjMF-86I8mgtNFYw=='}"

headerDict = ast.literal_eval(header)
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I changed the two double quotes inside the string in: `"default-src [...] https://a.1password.eu/"` from `"` to `""`

But still there is an error. Apparently from the content with `'self'` which contains single quotes.

I should not change the header content at all. However, if I apply a single rule, for example, replace every `"` with `""` this is possible solution. As I need to parse the header. It should maintain its original data and I should not change anything on it.

What is the solution in this case? This is one example, but I expect to see other variants. How to convert dict-like string into a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use triple-quoted strings:

```
import ast

header = """{'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Content-Security-Policy': "default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' https://www.google.com/ https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/; form-action 'self' https://agilemail.createsend.com/ https://www.createsend.com/t/subscribeerror https://www.createsend.com/t/securedsubscribe; frame-src https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/; connect-src 'self'", 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Amz-Cf-Id': 'XZOj8R9YBVEMbHv93beUYFIizxUbrGKL_LVrS1gjMF-86I8mgtNFYw=='}"""

ast.literal_eval(header)
```

Output:

```
{'Content-Type': 'text/html',
 'Content-Security-Policy': "default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' https://www.google.com/ https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/; form-action 'self' https://agilemail.createsend.com/ https://www.createsend.com/t/subscribeerror https://www.createsend.com/t/securedsubscribe; frame-src https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/; connect-src 'self'",
 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
 'X-Amz-Cf-Id': 'XZOj8R9YBVEMbHv93beUYFIizxUbrGKL_LVrS1gjMF-86I8mgtNFYw=='}
```